# Files on pendrive can be accessed by searching on pendrive, not visible normally

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-8, usb-flash-drive, ntfs

I used to open my NTFS File System pendrive on Windows 7. When I opened it on Windows XP, it opened a folder with a autorun file, this autorun file brought me to the content of my drive. The same happened with Windows 8. I thought that deleting that autorun file may allow me to open it directly on all OS. So I deleted that file. Since then, my pendrive shows that its 13gb full(which it already was), but doesn't show anything inside it. I can access files which are not visible by searching on pendrive. The newly copied files are directly accessible. I have also set the Show hidden files to true in Folder options. I neither remember names of all files and folders on the drive so that I can search and backup files, nor want to lose the files by Formatting.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My question is - How to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution on my own. I was in Folder Options. I unchecked 'Hide protected operating system files', tried, and found a new unnamed folder. I opened it, and all my files were there.

Comment: Glad to know that you solved your issue. But it is not advised to uncheck `Hide protected operating system files` option. Even now also I think your pendrive /computer is affected by virus.Do a deep scan with an updated antivirus.

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath I did that only for a moment, to copy paste the files in that folder to my pendrive's main folder. Well I really appreciate your support.